# mysqldump: Got errno 12 on write

Tags: mysql

I recently started getting these messages when I run a script that has been working without any issues for years.

The command seems to do its job, and the resulting file seems complete, which just adds to the mystery.

This is on a VPS, which has limited CPU and memory, so presumably I'm hitting one of those limits, but it would be helpful to know for sure.

So I looked for a reference about `mysqldump` error codes, and found nothing. There are similar questions on StackOverflow, but all for different `errno` numbers.

Comment: That's usually the result of hitting a memory limitation, so you may need to run the `mysqldump` process on another machine. It's also possible that your `/etc/my.cnf` specifies too much memory for MySQL for a machine of that spec.

Comment: Not really an option to run mysqldump on another machine. I don't have access to the machine's ```/etc/my.cnf``` file, and the user's ```.my.cnf``` just has a password. Might need to upgrade the VPS. But isn't it also weird that there's no reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR: If you Have Memory Issues in MySQLDump, Set max_allowed_packet (also use --quick for QuickMode)

Use this parameter to prevent memory leaks and overflows: [**`--max_allowed_packet=2M`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html).  The default value is `16M`, and the max allowed value for this is `64M`.  If this fails, try lower values.

#### Full Demo Usage

```
nice mysqldump
-u MYUSERNAME
-pMYPASSWORD
--max_allowed_packet=2M
-h DATABASEHOST
--default-character-set=latin1
--skip-set-charset
--no-tablespaces
-N --routines
--quick
--skip-triggers
DATABASENAME > OUTPUTFILE
```

- `nice`: Run this command with priority.
- `max_allowed_packet`: This solves the problem.
- `quick`: This is another attempt to reduce memory problems by doing chunking, but this will solve errno `6` (out of memory on mysql processing), and presumably not errno `12` (out of memory in linux process-handling), but I still do it to help with memory.  (Yes, `quick` was a bad name for this parameter.)

#### Diagnosing Error Code 12 (and Diagnosing Any Old Error Number)

You can always find out what an exit code means by using [**`errno()`**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).  Exit code 12 is for...

> `ENOMEM` — 12 : Cannot allocate memory

To see what an error code is, simply run this command in linux: `errno 12`, or whatever the number is.  To see all of the errors possible, run `errno -ls`.

Basically, your host is not allowing you the memory to do the backup command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about max_allowed_packet. I'll try it. As for the errno command: it doesn't seem to exist on the VPS I'm using. Works elsewhere though; thanks for that.

Comment: Good luck, let me know how it works out!